# Enthusiast and Fanatic badges should be counted in the user's local time

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, activity-badges

I am trying to get the Enthusiast badge. However, trying to coordinate my visits to the site with UTC time is hard.

There is no reason why you can't time these badges in the user's local time, either by IP address or a setting in the Profile. (If there is, comment.)

Answer (score 2):

> There is no reason why you can't time these badges in the user's local time

Of course there is. Time zones are difficult - this is why we do **everything** in UTC (which also helps with DST issues, as UTC does not have them).

Comment: Interesting case where the original question has no official answer, while a closed duplicate got one. Maybe reverse the dupe closure?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - the non official answers there have a more complete picture.